# Gitlab on a minimal requirement Server

Tags: ubuntu, installation, gitlab

I am trying to install gitlab for private use. I want to pay as less as possible so I took the cheapest server on ovh and after installing GitLab on Ubuntu I get following error page "502 Error GitLab is taking too much time to respond". How can I minimalize the memory use and will it ever run on 2GB Memory only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2G won't cut it. Gitlab is a notorious memory hog.

From the docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html

> 4GB RAM is the required minimum memory size

Official doc states flat out "Gitlab has memory leaks" (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/unicorn.html#unicorn-worker-killer)

More details:

https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/engineering/development/enablement/memory/

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17379523

Comment: Ok, so there is no way it could run there? Aren't there optional functions which can be turned off in order to save some memory?

Comment: In my experience running Gitlab locally, it wouldn't be able to run on a small host like that. You can try dropping down the unicorn worker process counts but in my opinion it's trying to fit it onto a system that just can't support the software.

Comment: Ok thank you, I upgraded to 4GB RAM and it works perfectly now.